# Why is my browser saying access to document element denied

Tags: dom, iframe, com, autohotkey

I am running the following Autohotkey code that works all the time on good days and most of the time on bad days (slow internet and or computer).

```
079: Sleep,500
081: ie_win.document.all.lbContentIframe.contentWindow.document.all.btnOkId.click()  
082: Sleep,500
083: While,ie_win.document.all.lbContentIframe.contentWindow.document.readyState <> "complete"
084: Sleep,100
```

The error I am getting is for line 83

Description:    Access is denied.

HelpFile:       C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.hlp

Specifically: document

Is that because the lbContentIframe Iframe document isn't loaded yet? Previously I have tried

`while !ie_win.document.getelementbyid("lbContentIframe")
sleep, 100`

and I haven't received any errors due to that line. Do I need to do that every time the Iframe might be refreshing before trying to check if it is done loading via the readyState property?

Also, once I get the above error it never starts working again no matter how many times I try. It is almost like the ie_win handle gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    While ie_win.readyState!=4 || ie_win.document.readyState!="complete" || ie_win.busy
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: As soon as an Iframe exists, doesn't the parent document consider its job done though? When a documents ready state is complete does that mean all of the sub frames are completely loaded? Because I have found that not to be the case. That is why I was waiting on the iframe to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that on several interactive web pages I would have to write a custom wait function based on a value I know will exist and be populated when the entire page is fully loaded.

Try Something like this:

```
ComObjError(false)
While (value == "") {
    value := ie_win.document.getElementsByClassname("YourElement")[1].innerText
    Sleep 100
    }
ComObjError(true)
```

Comment: This is what I have found to. That is pretty much what I am trying to do that is failing sometimes because of trying to access document at a bad time.

Comment: ComObjError(false) will keep your code from throwing an error, allow your loop to continue trouble free until your condition is met. Yes you, need to write a function to monitor when the website/iframe/updating